# No imprime el arreglo en su correspondiente JTextField

Tags: java, array

El programa es simple, se ingresa una serie de numeros (2, 3, 4, 5) ,y al apretar el botón Intercambiar Datos, la pantalla quiero que quede de esta forma:

Arreglo1 (2, 3, 4, 5) Arreglo 2 ( 5, 4, 3, 2)

El caso es que lo pone como se ve en la imagen. Sé que en el `for` se hace el proceso de inversión de arreglo1 y entonces igualo con arreglo2 por lo tanto tienen los mismos valores.  Entonces ¿como puedo hacer para que quede como lo necesito? Cada arreglo(el original) en su espacio Arreglo 1 y el inverso en Arreglo 2.

[image: ej]

Esto solo es una pequeña parte de todo el código. De ser necesario lo puedo poner todo

```
 private void dibujarArregloIntercambiar(int n)
    {
        panel1.setVisible(false);
        panel2.setVisible(false);
        panel.setVisible(false);

        panel1.removeAll();
        panel2.removeAll();
        panel.removeAll();

        // tfArreglo1, tfArreglo2 y panel1, panel2


        int max=arreglo1.length-1;
        for(int i=arreglo1.length-1;i>=0;i--) // for para invertir el arreglo.
        {
            arreglo2[max-i]=arreglo1[i];    
     //     System.out.println(arreglo2[max-i]);
     //     System.out.println(arreglo1[i]);

            tfArreglo2[max-i] = new JTextField(2);
            tfArreglo2[max-i].setText(arreglo2[max-i]);
            panel1.add(tfArreglo1[i]);

            tfArreglo2[i] = new JTextField(2);
            panel2.add(tfArreglo2[i]); 
        }

        // Hacer visibles los panels 1 y 2
        panel1.setVisible(true);
        panel2.setVisible(true);

        // Adicionar los panels 1 y 2 al panel de visualizacion
        panel.add(new JLabel("Arreglo 1 "));
        panel.add(panel1);

        panel.add(new JLabel("Arreglo 2 "));
        panel.add(panel2);

        panel.add(bIntercambiar);
        panel.add(bOrdenar);
        panel.add(bBuscar);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        // Adicionar panel de visualizacion al JFrame
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true); 
    }
```

Comment: Una de las manera sería que primero imprimas los valores del Arreglo1, luego recién haces el proceso de invertir el orden de tu arreglo pasándolo a tu Arreglo2 y por último mandarlo a imprimir. Todo esto en un solo botón. Saludos.

Comment: Si hago eso primero. Tal vez me falto explicarlo porque no está todo el código, pero primero se ingresa el arreglo y en un Menú al darle click a un MenuItem que tengo, lo imprime ASI COMO SE INGRESO, y al picarle al botón Intercambiar Datos, borra el input original y pone el inverso y no lo hace donde debería. que es conservar el arreglo original y en arreglos2 poner el inverso.

Comment: Quizá tampoco no me dejé entender muy bien. Mira, no debería de borrarte nada, al contrario debería de mostrarte las dos impresiones y ya que menciono eso, ¿esta imagen es cuando ya mandaste a intercambiar datos? Si es así, tu error estaría al mandar a imprimir, por ahí veo que creas dos instancias de **tfArreglo2**. Mi idea consiste que al pulsar el botón IntercambiarDatos vuelvas hacer la impresión, claro que cada textField con su correspondiente arreglo. Saludos

Comment: Otra forma quizá sería que en tu método Intercambiar Datos, en un arreglo2 estén los valores invertidos y luego mandar a imprimir este arreglo2 a sus textField correspondiente. Acabo de ver que esto sería mas óptimo, ya que no debería de alterarse tu arreglo original, ni los valores en tus textFields. Saludos.

Comment: Ya logre hacer que lo ponga en el segundo TextField, en el código cambie panel2.add(tfArreglo2[i]);  por panel2.add(tfArreglo2[max-i]); de tal modo que quedan igual . Si los datos son (1, 2, 3 ) queda (3, 2 , 1) en ambos TextField